# Designing PDF component for easy access

Tags: c#, itext, pdfsharp, aspose, pdfclown

I have seen open source and commercial PDF components which support Dot net implementation, I think almost every available component in market,but the strange to identify a document that is protected or not, every one is showing in the form of exception rather than a property.Is there anything tricky behind this?
I would expect

```
Component.Load(inputFile.pdf);
If(Component.isProtected)
{
Component.Open(inputFile.pdf,password);
}
else
{
Component.Open(inputFile.pdf);
}
```

instead of the following regular approach

```
Try{
Component.Open(inputFile.pdf);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//bad password
//Some exception
}
```

Comment: The main reason in my eyes is that there is hardly any use in a prior `Load` call as in case of an encrypted document with password there is hardly anything to do but say "Hey, I can't!" Furthermore your proposal still requires an exception to be thrown if no password or a wrong one is provided in the `Open` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx), which is a commercial .NET component. It has a boolean property [IsEncrypted](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/PdfFileInfo+IsEncrypted+Property) for encrypted file detection. Sample code is given below.

```
// load the source PDF doucment
PdfFileInfo fileInfo = new PdfFileInfo(dataDir + "protected.pdf");
// determine that source PDF file is Encrypted with password
bool encrypted = fileInfo.IsEncrypted;
MessageBox.Show("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
```

I work for Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks, it clears me, there is actually nothing reason for that kind of implementation. I like the one Aspose did it.Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

All can be detected basically by checking for the respective "dictionaries" as described on pages 115 - 136 of the PDF spec: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: +1 I understand the encryption applies to every string and every object in PDF file, which demands to go through the entire file and verify for encryption.This can help to define the encryption, you mean there is nothing behind about the current way of throwing exception to say pdf is encrypted during Open method.?